# Trouble setting up Segment with Next.js

Tags: next.js, analytics, segment

I've been trying to just integrate Segment with Next.js, and I'm not sure why inserting the shippet into the Head isn't working. For some reason Next.js doesn't understand the syntax of adding a `<script>` into the head like this:

```
export default function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <title></title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <script>
  !function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{analytics.invoked=!0;analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","debug","page","once","off","on","addSourceMiddleware","addIntegrationMiddleware","setAnonymousId","addDestinationMiddleware"];analytics.factory=function(e){return function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);t.unshift(e);analytics.push(t);return analytics}};for(var e=0;e<analytics.methods.length;e++){var key=analytics.methods[e];analytics[key]=analytics.factory(key)}analytics.load=function(key,e){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript";t.async=!0;t.src="https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/" + key + "/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n);analytics._loadOptions=e};analytics._writeKey="WRITE_KEY";;analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="4.15.3";
  analytics.load("WRITE_KEY");
  analytics.page();
  }}();
</script>
    </>
  )
}
```

This gives me errors.

I tried to use [this example with @segment/snippet](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-segment-analytics/pages/_app.js) to load Segment, but it also doesn't seem to work as expected.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `analytics.load("WRITE_KEY");` did you update this to be your actual Write Key from Segment?

Comment: @richessler Yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

Segment.io team relase an example with a nextjs integration [1]

```
import { AnalyticsBrowser } from '@segment/analytics-next'

const AnalyticsContext = React.createContext<AnalyticsBrowser>(undefined!);

type Props = {
  writeKey: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
};
export const AnalyticsProvider = ({ children, writeKey }: Props) => {
  const analytics = React.useMemo(
    () => AnalyticsBrowser.load({ writeKey }),
    [writeKey]
  );
  return (
    <AnalyticsContext.Provider value={analytics}>
      {children}
    </AnalyticsContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Create an analytics hook that we can use with other components.
export const useAnalytics = () => {
  const result = React.useContext(AnalyticsContext);
  if (!result) {
    throw new Error("Context used outside of its Provider!");
  }
  return result;
};

// use the context we just created...
const TrackButton = () => {
  const analytics = useAnalytics()
  return (
    <button onClick={() => analytics.track('hello world')}>
      Track!
    </button>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AnalyticsProvider writeKey='<YOUR_WRITE_KEY>'>
      <TrackButton />
    </AnalyticsProvider>
  )
```

I integrate this with my segment key and works like a charm.

[1] https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-next/tree/master/packages/browser

---

Edit:
It seems they leave the hook version for something more object-oriented [2]

*should* work as previous v
[2] https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-next/tree/master/packages/browser#nextjs

Comment: AFAICS the linked example has nothing to do with Next.js. The README doesn't mention Next.js and it's not listed as a dependency in the package.json. Not to say the example you provide doesn't work -- just pointing out the possible misconception and potential for confusion.

Comment: @DwightGunning Readme.md seems to be updated since I posted Now the example has been move https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-next/tree/master/packages/browser#nextjs I'll update mi response.

Comment: That explains it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to replace your "WRITE_KEY" with what your key